# Listing VMs under Manage Instance Group

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I want to list all VMs that are in Manage Instance Group using google cloud client libraries for .NET.
Application Type: Console App, .NET 7.0
Library: Google.Cloud.Compute.V1

```
RegionInstanceGroupManagersClient regionInstanceGroupManagersClient = await RegionInstanceGroupManagersClient.CreateAsync();
var vms = regionInstanceGroupManagersClient.ListManagedInstancesAsync("projectId", "region", "mig_name");
await foreach (var vm in vms)
{
    Console.WriteLine(vm.Instance);   
}
```

Error:

> Grpc.Core.RpcException: 'Status(StatusCode="InvalidArgument",
> Detail="Invalid value for field 'pageToken': ''. Supplied restart
> token corresponds to a zone not supported by this managed instance
> group.")'

I'm trying understand this issue as in documenation pageToken is not required in request. According to [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.Compute.V1/latest/Google.Cloud.Compute.V1.RegionInstanceGroupsClient#Google_Cloud_Compute_V1_RegionInstanceGroupsClient_ListInstancesAsync_System_String_System_String_System_String_Google_Cloud_Compute_V1_RegionInstanceGroupsListInstancesRequest_System_String_System_Nullable_System_Int32__Google_Api_Gax_Grpc_CallSettings_) if pageToken is not provided - first page will be retrieved.

Comment: Is your issue addressed? can you let us know if anything needs to be addressed.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a region based instance group to list the vms under managed instance group instead you need to use [InstanceGroupManager.Types.ListManagedInstancesResults.](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.Compute.V1/latest/Google.Cloud.Compute.V1.ComputeEnumConstants.InstanceGroupManager.ListManagedInstancesResults)

In this  you need to use the string `public const string Pageless = "PAGELESS"`

This will ignore the pageToken query parameters and return the results in a single response. Can you try this and post if you get any errors.

> [Pageless](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.Compute.V1/latest/Google.Cloud.Compute.V1.InstanceGroupManager.Types.ListManagedInstancesResults#fields) :  (Default) Pagination is disabled for the group's
> listManagedInstances API method. maxResults and pageToken query
> parameters are ignored and all instances are returned in a single
> response.